# What determines the first artifact in Lifeline 2?

Tags: lifeline-2

In Lifeline 2, Akira's goal is to collect 3 artifacts: A key, a ribbon, and a lantern.

On my first playthrough I was given the key as the first object to collect. However, when I played the game again, I was given the ribbon as my starting item instead.

<sub>*It may be worth noting that my friend also collected the key first on her initial playthrough</sub>

By abusing the "rewind" feature, I've seen that it is possible to get any of the 3 artifacts as the starting item, but it doesn't seem to be based on any choices or decisions made earlier in the story.

**What determines which artifact Akita collects first? Is it simply randomized?**

[image: collecting the ribbon first]